# Assign a scala.collection.immutable.Set variable to other variable

Tags: scala, set

I have a Set variable like this

```
val setValues= Set (10,20,30,40)
```

I want to assign one of them, for example 30 to other variable. how can i do that?

for example in other languages when we have array, we can write

```
int a=array(2)
```

and it will assign the value of position 3 of array to variable 'a' 
But how can I assign the value of position 2 of a 'Set' of values to other variable or check that whether it is equal to 80 or not?

I tried for example setValues(2), setValues->2 but the result is not 30 in this example

Comment: `val otherVariable = value(30)`? `val otherVariable = 30`? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You are asking questions that imply that you don't have basic math or computer science skills. Moreso than with most other OO languages like Java, these skills are quite necessary to do anything significant with Scala. For example, Set is unordered both in Java and in Scala. If you want to select based on an index, you could assign the set to something that is indexable; ex: an Array. Then sort the Array according to whatever criteria you need before accessing the Array via an index. BTW, I have intentionally not provided the exact answer because this feels like schoolwork/homework.

Answer (score 3):

`Set` = unordered set. `Seq` = indexable sequence

```
val seqValues = Seq(10,20,30,40)
seqValues(2)
```

For better performance, use `IndexedSeq` which has fast access. `seqValues(2)` is short for `seqValues.apply(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Sets are unordered, so you need some way to pick out a particular element--but if you already have that exact element you don't need to get it from the set (you've already got it!).  Maybe

```
val x = Set((0,"fish"),(1,"dish"),(2,"wish")).find(_._1 == 1).get
```

is what you want (i.e. `find` an element that obeys some condition other than perfect equality; this returns an `Option` which you can `get` if it is found)?

Comment: I want to use the value of that in other part of my program. for example I want to check from position 2 to end and pas some of the values to other function. Is it possible to go for specific position and get the value or not?

Comment: @user194611: it's a set. Sets are unordered. They don't *have* "positions".

Comment: @Rex Kerr Isn't another option to play with the method zipWithIndex to produce a set of tuples which could then be placed into a Map with the keys being the indexes and the values being the original Set values?

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium - Why make tuples when you can just stuff them into an array and index directly?  But the problem is that if you call `Set(0,1,2,3)` and you want `2`, you don't know where it is.  (Actually, you do, but it's a special case for tiny sets; with `Set(0,1,2,3,4,5)` the elements come out in order `0,5,1,2,3,4`.)

Answer (score 0):

Trivial answer?

```
val value = Set (10,20,30,40)
val variable = 30
```

You need to be more specific about the criteria you would use to pick which item would be set to the variable.  With a `Set`, you can't, for example, choose the first or last item because `Set`s are unordered.  You *can*, however, do something like setting the variable to be the max or min:

```
val variable = value.max
```